# Spring Boot not using application.properties for spring.groovy.template.cache

Tags: spring, groovy, spring-boot

I have a very simple Spring Boot application with classes detailed below.

My problem is with the application.properties file and how they get auto-configured. I'm trying to get Groovy Templates to update in dev by setting 'spring.groovy.template.cache: false', however this is not working. I added two more properties to see if the application.properties file was being read. The 'logging.level.org.springframework.web: ERROR' still results in INFO level messages printed to the console. However, some.prop is read correctly into the MyBean class on application start.

Is there a configuration declaration I'm missing for these properties?

src/main/resources/application.properties:

```
spring.groovy.template.cache: false
logging.level.org.springframework.web: ERROR
some.prop: bob
```

src/main/java/sample/MyBean.java:

```
@Component
public class MyBean {

    @Value("${some.prop}")
    private String prop;

    public MyBean() {}

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("================== " + prop + "================== ");
    }
}
```

and src/main/java/sample/Application.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

and src/main/java/sample/com/example/MainController.java

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView risk(@RequestParam Optional<String> error) {
        return new ModelAndView("views/login", "error", error);
    }

}
```

Comment: I never used the ":", perhaps it is not accepted for some parameters and you need to specify "=" instead ?

Comment: Marged is right.  The colon is used with YAML, properties files need an equals sign

Comment: They should work exactly the same. In fact, the springboot example projects on Github (spring-boot/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-groovy-templates) use ':' in their application.properties files.  However, I did test and it still does not function properly with '=' .

Comment: Are you only using auto config or do you have some custom configuration that interferes/disables auto configuration?

Comment: There shouldn't be anything disabling or interfering. The Application.java is the only src file I have other than one controller (edited question with controller).

Comment: And how are you testing the caching or not? For caching to be disabled I would also expect that you need to use groovy templates outside of the class path, else they won't reload (but that is a guess).

Comment: To test I was simply updating a p(class: 'lead'){... some text ...} (the some text part I was updating). The template is in src/main/resources/templates/views/index.tpl   -- I'm not sure of the utility of turning off caching if it won't allow you to update the templates in src/main/resources/templates ?  I tried turning off FreeMarker caching as well and I had the same problem... So maybe you are right, but again I don't see the utility of turning it off in dev if you are unable to hot reload. So maybe there is something still wrong in my configs in src/main/java/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the solution was much simpler than I thought:

```
gradle bootRun
```

**should be used to hot reload templates**

gradle run does not work (all compiled classes are just built in build/ )

Answer (score 0):

It seems you missing scanned your package "sample". Please make sure that you have scanned it.

```
@ComponentScan({
     "sample" })
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Also, your application.properties is right. No problem with it.